# Expected input number to be real matlab

Tags: matlab, types, double

I went to denoising my residuelle image  with a bilaatretl filter and with use of anscombe transform (GAT) for stabilsation the noise .the probeme is when i transform my image to the GAT it become complexe double 
I Have this erreor "**Expected input number 1, K1, to be real.**" 
my matrice is *<160x160 complex double>* so i think that i have  to convert this matrice to *<160x160  double>* to solve the probleme 
i tried **mat2gray** but didn't work
thanks

Comment: Do you know why the matrix was complex?

Comment: after i applicate the formule of GAT (stabilsation of noise),the image become complex

Comment: Did you have negative values in the Anscombe transform input? Are the imaginary components of the complex matrix all zero?